# How can I trigger an action after updating a Podio Category on zapier?

Tags: podio, zapier

I'm now on Zapier, but I'm using it to create a new integration of Podio (our CRM) and  Aweber (our mailing tool).

What I have?

- A CRM with name, e-mail, Status and other infos.

What I need?

- That when I update the Status of my Podio Item, a new subscriber is created on aweber.

What happens?

- I tried to make by using "Custom Value" in Status (that is a Category field in Podio). However, when I try it, Zapier shows me a message saying : "Hey there!
  I need to create a trigger everytime a category inside my podio app changes. The name of the category is "Status".

What I expect to happen?

- Whenever someone change the "Status" of this item in podio, the trigger is activated.

I tried to make it a trigger by using "Status" as a Field, "Use a Custom Value (advanced)" as a Action Type and the name of the category as "Custom Value for Action Type". However, when I tried to do that, it shows me:
[the following message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYsmZ.png)

What do I need?

- To make the update in a category field become a trigger so I can activate other actions on other tools. Can you help me? :D

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your idea correctly, you want to trigger a Zapier action on every change of a category field in Podio. So just set this field as one to be tracked and choose an action `Item.Update`. That's it. See the screenshot:
[image]

Note, that with this set up you will have an action triggered *every time* your category field got updated, whatever the change will be. So if you want to check the field change for a particular value (i.e. call an action when a category is set to "Approved" only) then I'm affraid you will have to use Podio API, or try manually check the value with Zapier next steps (like Run javascript or Python).

And as for your attempt to "Use a custom value" in the "Action type" field. To be able to track Podio triggers Zapier utilizes Podio API and adds hooks. Podio API supports a particular list of hooks, so you cannot just add a custom one. Here is a list of hoos available: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks